# PHP , mysql a boolean search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, boolean

I am a newbie in PHP, I hope someone can help me

I'm already pretty far but now I'm stuck.
The learning process I have done step by step, so there are some control rules in the code below.
The problem I have is to run the MySQL Query especially in the MATCH AGAINST function.
As you can see in the code I put a fixed value in the query at AGAINST. This works perfectly.
The query I generated by typing the query in phpAdmin and then after running the query 'create PHP code' clicking.

```
<?php
// not set?
if(!isset($_POST['omschrijving2'])) exit('nothing posted');
// get posted values
$keywords = $_POST['omschrijving2'];
$qualifier = $_POST['qualifier'];
//do the search and search using all the terms if 'all'
if ($qualifier == "all")
{
$words=explode(" ",$keywords);
//add + operator to each keyord
$keywords = '';
foreach($words as $word) {
$keywords .= "+".$word." ";
}
echo $keywords; // '+vleugel +model '
$keywords = rtrim($keywords); // remove last space
echo '<br>'.$keywords; // '+vleugel +model'
echo "is de keyword waarde";
}
else
{
echo "geen waarde in keywoord";
}
mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");
mysql_select_db('museum');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT omschrijving FROM `rapporten` WHERE MATCH (`rapnaam` ,       `omschrijving`)\n"
. "AGAINST (\"+vleugel +model\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) ");
if(!$query) {
echo mysql_error()."<br>$query<br>";
}
else
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<br />";
echo $row['omschrijving'];
echo "<br />";
}
}
?>
```

The problem I get is when I replace the fixed value in the query for the dynamic value `AGAINST ('$ keywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` then there is no value received.
If I change the value to `AGAINST ('.$ keywords.' IN BOOLEAN MODE..)");` Then I get this error; `Unknown column 'vleugel'` in 'where clause'
The third variation I tried this, `AGAINST (.$ Keywords IN BOOLEAN MODE)")`, resulting in an error message, `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual That corresponds ponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+vleugel +staart. IN BOOLEAN MODE) 'at line 2`
For all tests, I entered the value vleugel model in the form.

Any ideas how to fix this. I do not know if this is important but I use dreamweaver and mysql version 5.5.24 for this project.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing it with {$keywords}.

```
"SELECT omschrijving FROM `rapporten` WHERE MATCH (`rapnaam`, `omschrijving`) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```